# Lightning component: component visible event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-events

I have an aura component for case in service console. For every case tab opened, an instance of the component is created. I need a way to know when a component becomes "visible" or "active" (e.g. the case tab containing the component is opened or in focus). I couldn't find any aura event handler that fits my needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a combination of `TabFocused` event and `getEnclosingTabId` method like this:

CMP :

```
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
<aura:handler event="lightning:tabFocused" action="{! c.onTabFocused }"/>
```

Controller:

```
onTabFocused : function(component, event, helper) {
    var focusedTabId = event.getParam('currentTabId');
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(tabId) {
        if(tabId === focusedTabId){
            // This means you have focused this component
        }
        console.log(tabId);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Focused tab event gets triggered on all component instances, but the code inside your `if` will only execute if the current focused tab id is equal to your enclosed tab id. Which means you are focused on a component which is visble in current tab and not on other tabs.

Comment: Wow! exactly what i need!. Thanks so much!